# save data in shared preferences without overwriting old data

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I receive json data from my server that I save in my application with shared preferences.

```
 TextView mname;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin);

    mname = findViewById(R.id.name);

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(AdapterFish.MY_PREF,MODE_PRIVATE);
    String nom = sharedPreferences.getString(AdapterFish.NAME_KEY,"");
 }
 mname.setText(name);
```

everything goes well until the but I would like to save in the same view two or more different data without overwriting the previous ones. help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> save data in shared preferences without overwriting old data

You need to use different **`key`** to save different data in `SharedPreferences`

if you use same key to save data in `SharedPreferences` it will overwriting old data

As per my opinion better to use **`SQLite`**

> SQLite is an open-source relational database i.e. used to perform database operations on android devices such as storing, manipulating or retrieving persistent data from the database.
>
> It is embedded in android bydefault. So, there is no need to perform any database setup or administration task.

**[Android SQLite Tutorial 1](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-sqlite-tutorial)**

**[Android SQLite Tutorial 2](https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)**